# MVVM - Communication between Separated Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a `CustomerListViewModel` that contains a `ObservableCollection<Customer>`

`MainView` holds an instance of these views:

- `CustomerListView` - which creates an instance of `CustomerListViewModel`
- `SearchView` - which creates and instance of `SearchViewModel`

My question is, How do I keep the CustomerListView and the SearchView separated.
The SearchView should only be displayed if a Customer is selected. The only dependency for the SearchViewModel should be a `Customer` Model. If there isn't a Customer selected from the CustomerListViewModel, then the SearchView shouldn't be displayed.

Should I introduce a new View/ViewModel that contains both a `CustomerListViewModel` and `SearchViewModel` that can hold a reference to the Selected `Customer` and toggle the displaying of a SearchView? If not, how should I go about this?

I know this question is pretty broad, but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: That's what I'd do. A ViewModel that combines two or more ViewModels. The composite ViewModel can subscribe to events and toggle visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make MainView contain instances of CustomerListView and SearchView. All three of them should be separate.

As far as the communication between views is concerned, this should be done through the respective viewmodel using e.g mvvm-light messenger. If you register a different messenger with each view, then from a viewmodel you can send message to any view you want.

Just an example of the simplicity of using an MVVMLight Messenger:-

View:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, OpenViewMessageReceived);

private void OpenViewMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
{
    //Logic 
}
```

ViewModel:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage(someStr));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why you don't want to put the instances in MainView?

Comment: @Michael G, because that creates a strong coupling between those views(which is against mvmm pattern). Also it is not good to create an instance of vm in view, this should be done in a centralized location e.g. viewmodellocator(mvvmlight toolkit). You must really think of using mvvmlight toolkit. I've been working on a quite complex application, and the toolkit has really made a lot of tasks simpler for me.

Answer (score 1):

I actually wrote something recently that dealt with that [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/). You might be interested in checking it out.

Basically, if you can access your value from a RelativeSource Binding that is probably the simpliest way to do it

Something like `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainView}}, Path=DataContext.CustomerListViewModel.SelectedCustomer}`

Or implement a messaging system that broadcasts a message whenever the SelectedCustomer gets changed. MVVM Light Toolkit has a nice simple one using the `Messenger` class, or Prism had the more advanced `EventAggregator`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is nice article about communication between Views in MVVM: [Communication Between Views in MVVM (Pub-Sub Pattern)](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not to 'overkill' for you, you may checkout [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/)

It's a guideline with library for composite applications using MVVM and MEF. It's a very neat lib, but for small projects it might be oversized.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of PRISM; However, I'm not sure how PRISM would solve this architecture problem. Could you point me in the right direction?