# Property in ViewModel not displayed in View

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datacontext

I have a ViewModel called MainWindowViewModel. In this I have a property that shows a modal window when an error occurs. This works fine as long as an error occurs during start-up.

When an error occurs after start-up, in SubViewModel, I invoke the parametrized constructor in MainWindowViewModel.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    if (!isServerRunning)
    {
        this.ModalWindow = new LogViewModel("Server is down.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.ModalWindow = new LogViewModel();
    }
}


public MainWindowViewModel(string logMessage)
{
    this.ModalWindow = new LogViewModel(logMessage);
}


public LogViewModel ModalWindow
{
    get
    {
        return _modalWindow;
    }
    set
    {
        _modalWindow = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("ModalWindow");
     }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

....

```
<Grid>
    <vw:LogView Content="{Binding Path=ModalWindow}"/>
</Grid>
```

- MainWindowViewModel is bound to MainWindow.xaml
- SubViewModel is bound to SubView.xaml
- MainWindow.xaml loads multiple views, one of them is SubView.

In **App.xaml** I have created an instance of the ViewModel and bound it to MainWindow.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{                                  
    base.OnStartup(e);
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

What I realized was that the modal window shows up when an error occurs after start-up if I create the modal window property in SubViewModel and bind it to SubView. But this is not ok since SubView is only a DockPanel covering 1/4 of the MainWindow. I.e. 1/4 is only covered with a modal window instead of the whole MainWindow.

I am not sure why modal window does not appear in MainWindow when I call the parametrized constructor from SubViewModel. When I debug I see that the part `_modalWindow = value;` has correct values but in any case the modal window does not show up.

I am binding the ViewModel to the Datacontext of the MainWindow. That's is probably why I see the Modal window when error occurs on start-up. For errors after start-up: Must I (from SubViewModel where I invoke the parametrized constructor in MainWindowViewModel) do some kind of binding to the datacontext of the Mainwindow again? How is the best way of doing this without having to create a new instance of MainWindow? Because MainWindow should only be created once.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are recreateing the ViewModel every time an error occours. If so you would need to reset the binding in the view as well, which would defeat the purpose of MVVM. 
Rather have one instance of the ViewModel and propagate the errors to the View using OnPropertyChanged().

There are of course many ways of doing this, but I usually keep a reference to the ViewModel in my View, and then a reference to the Model in the ViewModel. This way the Model is completely decoupled from the View/ViewModel and likewise the ViewModel is decoupled from the View.

Comment: @Tele von Plan. If you hold a reference of ViewModel in the View then how is it decoupled? It is only fine in the case of Model/Viewmodel, since you need to call model functions from Viewmodel. But in the case of Viewmodel/View, these should be totally decoupled. This can be achieved by binding viewmodel properties to view, but not including any references of viewmodel in view.

Comment: Well.. I guess that a more straight forward (and standard) approach would be to assigning the DataContext of the view to the viewmodel. This satisfies "no code-behind".  But this does still involve holding a reference to the viewmodel, so its more or less the same thing..

Comment: what i mean with decoupled is that the viewmodel does not know about the existence of the view, as well as the model does not know about view or viewmodel.

Comment: @Tele von Plan. I don't take that approach. Rather I use binding there aswell and use a locator to resolve the viewmodel rather than constructing viewmodel. I.e. I do this <Window ... DataContext="{Binding NewWatchVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >...</Window>.

Comment: @Tele von Plan. Yes it is decoupled in that sense. But I believe resolving a viewmodel is better than constructing it. Besides check this [link](http://www.paulstovell.com/mvvm-instantiation-approaches) for 8 ways of Instantiation in MVVM.

Comment: Seems like a nice approach that is offered by the toolkit. I would still, however, argue that you do hold a reference to the viewmodel. This is just a matter how you assign it, and as I write in my answer there are many ways of doing this. Your approach is good im sure, but there are alternatives (and not all of us use mvvmlight toolkit).

Comment: Great article about the "8 ways of Instantiation in MVVM" - url saved. It summarizes this discussion quite well i think...

Comment: Hi Tele von Plan,

Also thanks for answering.

I am using OnPropertyChanged() to show the error message. But there seems to be a binding problem which I don't know how to solve.

I would like to use this approach if it is possible because I have a complrte modal window for this which works fine on start-up but I am stuck when trying to get it work for other errors after start-up.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating new instances of the viewmodel every time the error occours. The view is probably correctly bound to the first instance of the viewmodel (as you can see the any start-up errors). But creating a new instance of thev viewmodel will not automatically update the binding on the view, instead it is probably still bound to the first viewmodel. Instead of creating new viewmodels, try to update the property directly on the existing viewmodel instance. I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes Tele von Plan that is probably the reason. I will test your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Tele von Plan, now it works! I just passed the instance MainWindowViewModel to SubViewModel and used that instance in SubViewModel to set the property in MainWindowViewModel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not create MainWindowViewModel again and again. It should be created once and set to the datacontext of the mainwindow.

The problem is with the approach that you are taking to show dialog boxes. This is making things complicated.

The best solution to show dialog boxes is to use mvvmlight toolkit's messenger. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281196/mvvm-communication-between-separated-views/6281319#6281319) for some hints on it's usage.

This is how you could use mvvmlight toolkit's messenger to show dialogboxes:

View:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
         view,
         msg =>
         {
             var result = MessageBox.Show(
                 msg.Content,
                 msg.Caption,
                 msg.Button,
                 msg.Icon);
         }
);
```

ViewModel:

```
private void ShowMessageBox(string msgStr, string capStr, MessageBoxButton btn, MessageBoxImage img)
{
        var message = new DialogMessage(msgStr, null)
        {
            Button = btn,
            Caption = capStr,
            Icon = img
        };

        Messenger.Default.Send(message);
}
```

Just call the above method (ShowMessageBox) from any viewmodel to show a dialogbox.

Comment: Hi Hasan, 

Thanks for answering.

I am not familiar with Messenger toolkit. The "Messenger.Default.Register..." should be placed in codebehind of MainView.xaml, but I see that Messenger does not exist in the current context. What do I need to complement with?

I guess DialogMessage is just a class I need to create which takes the messageString as parameter in the constructor? I am not sure why null is needed as second parameter. Or can DialogMessage be found in an assembly reference?

Comment: @Kurmanc. Download the toolkit from [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). It provides you two dlls. You need to add reference to these dlls in your project - GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4 & GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4. Then add this namespace "using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;". Hopefully everything will work well. This [link](http://www.galasoft-lb.ch/mvvm/) contains information about the toolkit & provides instruction to install it.